# fadeIn and fadeOut within an infinite loop

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have different elements under one class, I want them to fadeIn and fadeaOut randomly within an infinite loop. I can get them to fadeIn randomly now, but stuck at fading out the elements.

And another thing is, after fadeOut, I want to delay a few second, before fading them in again.

This is my code snippet, hope it will help.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.share').each(function(i){
        var rand = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 7);//max of random 7 seconds
        $(this).fadeIn(rand*1000).delay(500).fadeOut(); 
    });
});
```

Comment: For questions of yours that have a good answer, click the checkmark next to the best answer.

Comment: No worries guys, will catch up with the reputation points in time. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the intervals between the fades to be randomized as well, you can use this:

```
$('.share').each(function(i) {
    loopInfinitely($(this));
});

function loopInfinitely(elem) {
    var rand = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 7) * 1000;//max of random 7 seconds
    setTimeout(function() {
        elem.fadeIn(rand).delay(300).fadeOut(rand);
        loopInfinitely(elem);  
    }, rand);
}
```

---

If you also want the elements to appear and disappear in order, you could use the following:

```
loopInfinitely($('.share'));

function loopInfinitely(elems) {
    var rand = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 7) * 1000;//max of random 7 seconds
    setTimeout(function() {
        var i = 0;
        (function advanceElem() {
            if (elems.length <= i) {
                loopInfinitely(elems);
                return;
            }
            elems.eq(i).fadeIn(rand).delay(300).fadeOut(rand);
            setTimeout(advanceElem, rand*2+300);
            i++;
        })();
    }, rand);
}
```

Let me know how this works.

Comment: I tried your code and it gave me uncaught type error : cannot call fadeIn of undefined, did I do something wrong?

Comment: @ocinisme - No, I found a mistake in my code (only the first call was being passed the element). Try again.

Comment: Thanks dude, it worked. Btw, how could I adjust the fadeIn and fadeOut speed so it could look like as in the elements are appearing and went missing one by one nicely?

Comment: @ocinisme - Edited answer to show how. Let me know if it works.

Comment: it works fine, just that all the animation still starts together. Any trick to make them animate one by one? Sorry for being so picky tho.

Comment: @ocinisme - Sorry, I forgot about the asynchronous nature of jQuery animations. I've updated the code. This will _hopefully_ work. I also noticed the random time was between 1 and 7 milliseconds rather than seconds, so I changed that to be between 1 and 7 seconds.

Comment: @ocinisme - Good to hear. :) And no problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular JavaScript timer to periodically invoke your code.

```
setInterval(function() 
    { 
        $('.share').each(function(i) 
        {
             var rand = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 7);//max of random 7 seconds
             $(this).fadeIn(rand*1000).delay(500).fadeOut(); 
        }) 
    },  3000);
```

Comment: I would avoid using `setInterval` with asynchronous calls. In my experience, it always back fired at some point.

Answer (score 0):

Make a `fade_element_in()` function with `$('.share').fadeIn()` inside it, and a `fade_element_out()` function. Then within each function use Javascript's `setInterval` function to call the other function after your preferred delay. Viola, infinite loop.